# YANG and SMI/MIB Compatibility

Tags: mib

Are they both interconvertable?

YANG -> MIB
MIB -> YANG

Thanks,
VJ

Answer (score 0):

look at libsmi
http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/
it suports SMI -> Yang conversion.
you can also use the web interface http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/tools/ to convert to Yang

Answer (score -1):

We can convert MIB to Yang by using smidump.

I think the current version libsmi-0.4.8.tar.gz supports it in this link
(https://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/download/libsmi-0.4.8.tar.gz)

**Syntax:**

smidump  -f yang --yang-smi-extensions --yang-indent 3 --output outputfile.yang input.mib

This will do it :)

Reg Yang to MIB i am still searching..
pls do help.

Thanks